# Getting an index exceeds matrix from a script that works for other databases

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, size

```
    clear
clc
%Loading data into matlab
%Left
dataleft = cell(1,20);
for n = 1:20
    foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\Free run\\Center Left P%d\\1.5D', n);
    filename = ['LP' num2str(n)];
    dataStruct.(filename) = dir( fullfile(foldername, '*.dat'));
    dataleft{n} = cell(1, numel(dataStruct.(filename)));
        for di = 1:numel(dataStruct.(filename));
        dataleft{n}{di} = importdata(fullfile(foldername,dataStruct.(filename)(di).name));
        end
end

%Right
dataright = cell(1,20);
for n = 1:20
    foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\Free run\\Center Right P%d\\1.5D', n);
    filename = ['LP' num2str(n)];
    dataStruct.(filename) = dir( fullfile(foldername, '*.dat'));
    dataright{n} = cell(1, numel(dataStruct.(filename)));
        for di = 1:numel(dataStruct.(filename));
        dataright{n}{di} = importdata(fullfile(foldername,dataStruct.(filename)(di).name));
        end
end

%Combine data
%Data planes are setup as if looking at the turbine from behind.
%Data points start on the left. Right-hand side wrt recorded experimental
%data.
datarightREV = fliplr(dataright);
dataCOMB = [datarightREV,dataleft];

%Name Variables
%Velocity (U component) Data Structure
U_Velocity = [];
for aa = 1:38 
    bb = aa;
    for cc = 1:40
    fieldname = sprintf('U_Velocity%04d', aa + (cc-1)*38);
    U_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,2);
    MeanU_Velocity.(fieldname) = mean(U_Velocity.(fieldname));
    end

end
```

I have the above code wrote and it works for all my other databases except for one. It import all the .dat files from my hard drive and creates a datastruct called dataCOMB. Within this there are 40 sub columns and within each of the 40 sub columns there are a further 38columns of data. When I rin the scripts i get the error  Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

```
Error in Load_Files_FR_15D (line 42)
    U_Velocity.(fieldname) = dataCOMB{1,cc}{1,bb}(1:1024,2);
```

I dont understand this as the values for cc and bb have not changed.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Jer

Comment: It may be possible that the database in question is of a different size in comparison to your other databases.  Are you absolutely sure all databases are the same size?

Comment: Yes. This script works for all databases except one. Even thought the matrix dimensions for dataCOMB do not change and I checked.

Comment: Use the debugger: run `dbstop if error`, which will drop you to a prompt at the error site.  Inspect ALL variables involved.  One of them is not the size you think it is.